# Two rotational stiffnesses?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image]

I was reading a paper "Torsion balances with fibres of zero length" by Speake and Collins. In which an levitated bearing is stabilised with an actuator (see the figure, there is two electrostatic plates or two magnets etc.). Not as shown in the figure a rotation will cause a change in stored energy and hence have a stiffness. The paper says that there are two stiffnesses,

[image]

One is a change in the gap caused by a rotation (this i understand) and the other is by storing energy caused by the rotation without a change in the gap (this i don't understand).

I am applying this the a magnetic actuator (a coil and a permanent magnet). i ask this question in general terms however i include my maths for the magnetic actuator as well. Not understanding the second stiffness I have only calculated one.
[image]

Comment: The only way there can be two stiffnesses is if the system has two degrees of freedom. If you decouple radial movement (gap) and rotation you will have two stiffnesses.